# How does IntelliJ run a main class without it being specified in the build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I click the Run Buttton in IntelliJ on a main class, it runs the gradle build with all the tasks.
[image]

However, I do not have a task that specifically runs the program (`Main.main`) (no `gradle run` functionality). How can I mimic that call to `Main.main` through the terminal without modifying the build.gradle (like how IntelliJ is doing)?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA generates a Gradle script to run it. You can't do it from the terminal in the same way IntelliJ IDEA does.

You can [disable Gradle delegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Sk.png) to run directly via the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a project without gradle to do this.

[Select new project -> Java -> Intellij -> Add sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ7bm.png)

[Run Main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRQg3.png)

Tested in Intellij 2022.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).